# Dot Net Core Web API Return Response From Endpoint

Tags: .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm busy trying to create a very simple Dot Net Core Web API (Dot Net 5) and I've run into a strange issue where I cannot get the endpoint to return a response.

I've tried to use

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
```

as per the documentation but I'm getting the error

```
'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'WriteAsync'
```

This is the full `Startup.cs` code

```
public class Startup {

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapGet("/test", async context => {
                //Console.WriteLine("Exec Test");
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });

    }

}
```

I'm sure there's something I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll which contains the WriteAsync method you are looking for based on the HttpResponse.

Please refer to the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsewritingextensions.writeasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0

https://www.carlrippon.com/asp-net-5-hello-world/

Comment: I was missing the reference `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`, thanks a bunch!